# How to create a column of continuous date?

Tags: sas

How do I create a column of date like this in SAS with the first day of month for each observation?

01/01/2007

02/01/2007

...

10/1/2012

11/1/2012

Should I use some kind of do-loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a loop is easy.  Here is one of many possible solutions:

```
data want;
   format first_of_month yymmdd10.;
   first_of_month = mdy(1,1,2007);
   do until (first_of_month > mdy(11,1,2012));
      output;
      first_of_month = intnx('month',first_of_month,1);
      end;
run;
```

This generates the data range you asked about (a series of "first of the month" dates from January 1, 2007 through November 1, 2012.